# getting "error adding symbols: File format not recognized" error while cross compiling QT5 for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, qt5, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, linaro

```
    -lpthread -lm /home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/qtbase/lib/libqtpcre2.a   
/home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/qtbase/lib/libqtpcre2.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1303: /home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.12.12] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/qtbase/src/corelib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:227: sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:51: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sincap/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12/qtbase'
make: *** [Makefile:82: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I'm trying to cross compile qt5 from ubuntu to raspberry pi3 and got this error while compiling. I'm using configuration below.

```
./configure -release -no-opengl -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/linarold/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -opensource -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm -skip webengine
```

Any idea how I can fix this? or How else can I cross compile qt5?